# Javascript array : AJAX, JSON

Tags: arrays, ajax, json

I'm a newbee to JS , JSON and AJAX. I'm using it to develop a simple apps in my SAP env. I'm bit struck in converting the AJAX response to java array. What is have in the code is:

```
function addTable()
{
    var urls = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var params = getURLParam().split('?');
        $.post("GetBayDetails.htm", {url: getURLParam(), params: params[1]})
                .done(function (data)
                {
                    var url = $.parseJSON(data);
                    urls.push(JSON.parse(url));
                    $.each(url, function (i, v)
                    {
                        push.urls[i] = v.bay;
                    });
                });
    });
    alert(urls[2]);
}
```

but if I loop through "URLS" I do not see any value appended to the array. Please can anyone provide some help to get this fixed?

Comment: You're already parsing the response with `$.parseJSON`, you shouldn't need to call `JSON.parse` on it again.

Comment: Please post an example of what the response JSON looks like.

Comment: Hi, json looks like {"bay": "B01", "url": "thtrack1"}, {"bay": "B02", "url": ""}, {"bay": "B03", "url": "not defined"}, {"bay": "B04", "url": ""}, {"bay": "B05", "url": "colm2"}, {"bay": "B06", "url": ""},

Comment: That's not valid, an array needs `[ ... ]` around it. Please post the actual JSON in the question.

Comment: the methods in SAP returns the json as: [{"bay": "B01", "url": ""}, {"bay": "B02", "url": ""}, {"bay": "B03", "url": ""}, {"bay": "B04", "url": ""}, {"bay": "B05", "url": ""}, {"bay": "B06", "url": ""} ....]

Comment: if i do an alert(v.bay) i could see the values but not when mapping to an array....is something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. My changes are:

1. Use the `"json"` dataType argument to `$.post` so it parses the response automatically.
2. There's no need to use `$(document).ready()` inside a function that you call on demand. This is only needed when performing initial actions that have to wait for the DOM to be loaded.
3. It's not necessary to call `JSON.parse(url)`, as this is already parsed.
4. The correct way to add to the `urls` array is `urls.push(v.bay)`.
5. The preferred way to initialize an array is with `[]`, not `new Array()`.
6. `alert(urls[2])` needs to be in the `.done()` function. Otherwise you're alerting before the AJAX call has completed.

```
function addTable() {
    var urls = [];
    var params = getURLParam().split('?');
    $.post("GetBayDetails.htm", {url: getURLParam(), params: params[1]}, "json")
        .done(function (url) {
        $.each(url, function (i, v) {
            urls.push(v.bay);
        });
        alert(urls[2]);
    });

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yf8ek1d6/5/)

Comment: thnk u barmar, unf this doesn't work either for me....just taking more time to identify the issue here!

Comment: thkx it okay now but if i have to refer the array outside the "post" it doesn't work...anything to be done for that?    pls advise

Comment: when i tried it just before the closing paranthesis of the addTable i get the msg as undefined....what shoud i do to make it visible out side the post? pls let me know

Comment: Everything that depends on an AJAX call must be done in the callback function -- see my change #6. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: may i ask a question in this post please? is it possible to access the dynamic table creation within the callback?

Comment: Yes, you can do pretty much anything you want in the callback.